# jQuery TE implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have been attempting to use the jQuery TE plugin to use for inserting articles, however the text area - even with all the styles - just appears as a narrow text area with no additional features.

The documentation on 'http://jqueryte.com/documentation' seems simplistic and straight forward, however there are no feature changes.

How do you implement jQuery TE correctly? Finding very little information available online.

The script tags inside the  tags are:

```
    <!-- jQuery Text Editior -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../controller/jquery-te-1.4.0.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../controller/jquery-te-1.4.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>






<form class="article" id="article-form" name="article" method="post">
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <label for="heading">Heading</label> <span id="headingMessage"></span>
                            <input name="heading" id="heading" class="form-control" type="text">
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="topic">Topic</label> <span id="topicMessage"></span>
                            <input name="topic" id="topic" class="form-control" type="text" list="football">
                            <datalist id="football">
                                <option value="Scotland"></option>
                                <option value="England"></option>
                                <option value="Spain"></option>
                            </datalist>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="summary">Summary</label> <span id="summaryMessage"></span>
                            <input name="summary" id="summary" class="form-control" type="text">
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="thumbnail">Thumbnail Link</label> <span id="thumbnailMessage"></span>
                            <input name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" class="form-control" type="text">
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="video">Video</label> <span id="videoMessage"></span>
                            <input name="video" id="video" class="form-control" type="text" >
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="articleText">Text</label>

                            <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" class="jqte-test"></textarea>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                        <input class="btn btn-success" id="formButton" type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit" name="submit">
                        <input class="btn btn-danger" id="formButton" type="reset" value="Reset">
                </form> 

                <script>
                    $('#textarea').jqte();
                </script>
```